# How to render data in groups to ejs

Tags: node.js, json, group-by, rendering, ejs

I want to  display data that has been grouped into the EJS?

I have the following data:

```
    "results": {
    "Angular CLI": [
        {
            "category_name": "Angular CLI",
            "article_title": "Mengenal Framework Angular CLI"
        }
        ],
       "Tips dan Trik": [
        {
            "category_name": "Tips dan Trik",
            "article_title": "Tutorial : Cara Membuat Repositori Github Private"
        },
        {
            "category_name": "Tips dan Trik",
            "article_title": "Mengenal Fitur Media Query pada CSS"
        }
           ]
              }
```

Following on the EJS file:

```
<% results.forEach(function(data) { %>
  <div>
    <p><%= data %></p>
  </div>
<% }); %>
```

But it does not display data at all.

**EDIT :**

Dear all, thank you for giving some explanation. So that I can find a solution to this problem.

```
<% for (let category in results) { %>
  <b><%= category %></b>
    <% results[category].forEach((data, key) => { %>
      <p><%= data.article_title %></p>
    <% }) %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Could you check out the browser console?
`results` is an object, whereas `forEach()` is an array method. Thus, I would expect the browser to throw an error.

Comment: you are trying to loop results.forEach your results but it is not array it's an object

Comment: @Wasbeer I am still learning. then how is the right way to display the data in the ejs file

Comment: sorry i forgot that. Is there a way to display the data to EJS? @Prakash Karena

Comment: You could convert your `results` to an array containing items that you want to render. Then loop over the array.
Important question: what do you want to render?

Answer (score 0):

Provided your object is something like this below

```
 var obj = {"results": {
    "Angular CLI": [
        {
            "category_name": "Angular CLI",
            "article_title": "Mengenal Framework Angular CLI"
        }
        ],
       "Tips dan Trik": [
        {
            "category_name": "Tips dan Trik",
            "article_title": "Tutorial : Cara Membuat Repositori Github Private"
        },
        {
            "category_name": "Tips dan Trik",
            "article_title": "Mengenal Fitur Media Query pada CSS"
        }
           ]
              }
```

As your `obj.results` is object and not array, you could iterate through all properties of `obj.results` object and display values like this

```
<% for (var prop in obj.results) { %>
  <div>
    <p><%= prop%> : <%= results[prop] %></p>
  </div>
<% }); %>
```

Let me know if I misunderstood your issue